# Game client interaction

Tags: python, server

I have a small game that has a small client, the game receives data from a server. The client is in a module and the game in another. The problem is that the client receives data from the server, but to perform actions in the game, the client needs to access methods of the game(class MyGame), with a code like this I get an error:

module client:

```
class MyClient:
    #receives data from the server
    #It is a task, always listening
    def readerConnection:
        #if a data arrives from the server...
        if newData:
            #call dataOnScreen of class MyGame
            ...dataOnScreen()
```

module game:

```
from client import MyClient

class MyGame:
    def _init_(self, client):
        #begin to receive data from the server
        self.c = client

    #print data received from the server on screen
    def dataOnScreen(self):
        ............
#the game begins        
MyGame(MyClient())
```

of course, an error occurs because the method dataOnScreen is not defined in the class MyClient.
if I do the following, things work fine (write the client into the game):

```
class MyGame:
    def _init_(self):
        .........
    #receives data from the server
    #It is a task, always listening
    def readerConnection:
        #if a data arrives from the server...
        if newData:
            #call dataOnScreen 
            self.dataOnScreen()

    #print data received from the server on screen
    def dataOnScreen(self):
        ............
#the game begins        
MyGame()
```

but this is not what I want. What I want is to have the game and the client in different classes.

appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm assuming you want the client and server to be communicating over a network. In that case, you can't simply call a function from one on the other, you will need to use some sort of network protocol to communicate from one to the other.

Comment: I think they're OK with the server / client comms, it's the linkage / separation of the actual game and client classes that's the issue (I think).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like pass the function or MyGame object into the client, so it knows what to do when it receives data.

Something like

```
class MyGame:
    def _init_(self, client):
        #begin to receive data from the server
        self.c = client
        client.game = self


class MyClient:
    #receives data from the server
    #It is a task, always listening
    def readerConnection:
        #if a data arrives from the server...
        if newData:
            #call dataOnScreen of class MyGame
            self.game.dataOnScreen()
```

Kind of like a context for the client or a callback if you passed in a function.